# How to free the consumption of memory from Memory Pool for Training on GPU?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, memory-leaks, chainer, cupy

Allocation of Memory using cupy throws an Out of Memory allocation problem.Consumption of memory out of 12 GB gets almost completed before even starting training. Now,during training all the memory is consumed.

Everything is working fine on CPU.

I have tried reducing batch size from 100 to single digit(4).
I have changed the small task into numpy since cupy consumes memory.
I have tried using more than one gpu but encounter same problem

[please_refer_this](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/vae/train_vae.py)

- Please note, It work's on CPU *

Results are fine but I need to trained more for that using cupy and GPU is necessary.

Comment: Are you trying the VAE example code as is? How much memory does it use in CPU mode?

Comment: Yes,But I am using my own data set.Input dimension is (512*512 * 4).CPU takes 25.375 GB. @SeiyaTokui

Comment: @SeiyaTokui In VAE I have removed the binary section as I am using own custom data function.Out of memory has become very serious problem,Can you give some insights on it.If any more information is required please tell ?

Comment: For dataset and all i am using iterator and genrators.[DataFeeding](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.dataset.DatasetMixin.html)@SeiyaTokui

Comment: When training some data is generated e.g after each epoch and all the final model files from previous training. Please find and delete them and try again.